# Run An Function Only Once Per App Installation In React Native ( Class Component )

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

So I Have A Issue Here I Just Want To **Run An Function Only Once In The App**

I Need To Initialize An Empty Array Only Once To The Async Storage . The I Will Do Read And Write Functions In The Array Later On Using ComponentWillMount() ...

The Issue Is How Do I Initialise A Empty Array at First And I Don't Want It To Be Empty Later On ( Like When The App Is Closed And Opened )

Each Time The Screen Renders I Read The Data Stored In The Async Storage ... But When The Screen Renders For The First Time The App Is Installed ... I Have Not Called The Below Function

```
setObjectValue = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(this.state.data)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('Emails', jsonValue)
    this.setState({ value : this.state.data.length })
  } catch(e) {
    // save error
  }
  console.log('Done.')
}
```

But In Case I Call It Before The Reading ... It Erases The Existing Data And Sets It To An Empty Array ( Becuase I Have An Contructor Which Has data: [ ] ) so when i read the data i get an empty array

You Can See The Full Code Here - https://snack.expo.io/@belgin/budget-tracker

Thanks To Any One Who Helps : )

Comment: You are already reading the array and setting it using getMyObject what is the problem here ?

Comment: Ya But The First Time The App Runs It Doesn't  ( Because I Havnt Uploaded Any Value Yet ) When The App Renders The Screen For The First Time ... It Will Try To Read The Object Which Has Not Been Initialized In The Async Storage ( setObjectValue Not Called )

Comment: yes but you can set an empty array if the email is not available in async storage right ?

Comment: Ya But It When I Do That Each Time The Screen Renders The Value Of The Array Becomes Empty

Comment: If You Run This https://snack.expo.io/@belgin/budget-tracker ... You Can Notice That The New Email Button Does Not Give Any Response When  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is Used ... But When I Remove This Set Of Code ... It Works

Comment: I think the problem is the way you are calling set and get instantly, checking it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224282/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-belgin-android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few changes that are required in your app.

First replace UNSAFE_componentWillMount with componentDidMount

And change your getMyObject like below which will make sure that it only updates if the value is there

```
 getMyObject = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Emails');
      if (jsonValue) {
        const data = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
        this.setState({ data: data, value: data.length });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // read error
    }
  };
```

Also remove the setState calls from the functions that you update the asyncStorage this will show invalid data as your calls are done while the state is not updated.

Also you can update the asyncStorage after the state is updated like below

```
this.setState({ data: this.state.data },()=>this.setObjectValue());
```